# Lower bound problem

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if S is a set of integers and m is a lower bound of S, then if $x<m$, then $x$ is also a lower bound of S.

The proof seems trivial, but is this all that is needed to show?

Proof:

Since m is a lower bound of S, $m \leq s$, $\forall s \in S$

If $x<m$,   then $x<m\leq s$

$\implies x<s$ So x is also a lower bound for S.

Comment: Yes, that is all you need to proof!

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all specific to the integers; this holds in any partial order, and the proof is just the same as yours:

Suppose $m$ is a lower bound of $S$ and $x < m$, then let $s \in S$ be arbitrary. 
Then $m \le s$ as $m$ is a lower bound of $S$. By transitivity of the order 
$x < m$ and $ m \le s$ together imply $x \le s$ (even $x < s$) and as $s$ was arbitrary, $x$ is a lower bound for $S$.

That's really all there is to it: just axiom of order plus definitions.